# I need some help understanding this bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I've been googling each parameter etc in this script trying to understand what each line is saying (if that makes sense). I wondered if anyone would be kind enough to help me out by helping me 'translate' into plain English what everything means? I've done the first 5 lines but I'm not sure if it's correct :/ Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
current=0
while [ $SECONDS -le 10 ]; do
    if [ $SECONDS -eq ${current} ]; then
        echo ${current}
        current=$((${current}+1))
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is a nifty little script highlighting how $SECONDS works in bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The magic of built-in bash variable $SECONDS

Your script highlights the built-in bash variable `$SECONDS` that keeps track of how many seconds a bash script has been running. Initially it starts at zero and the working variable `current` is set to this value at the beginning of the script. Then the script loops and increments `current` each time $SECONDS changes and displays "1, 2, 3... 10" on the screen.

---

## Analyzing bash script line by line:

`#!/bin/bash` tells the system this is a bash script

`current=0` sets the variable **current** to 0

`while [ $SECONDS -le 10 ]; do` When the number of seconds this script has been running is less than or equal to 10 do the following

`if [ $SECONDS -eq ${current} ]; then` if the value of current is equal to number of seconds then:

`echo ${current}` display the current value (0 initially, then 1, 2, 3... to 10)

`current=$((${current}+1))` increment current value

`fi` End of If statement, required for syntax rules

`done` end of While loop, required for syntax rules

---

## Testing the script

To test this script copy and paste the OP's text to a new file. For our purposes call the file `seconds`. Mark the file as executable with the command:

```
chmod +x seconds
```

Then call the bash script with the current directory prefix in front:

```
./seconds
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to get as far as echo ${current} but had no idea what the next line after that meant. Is there any reason behind the different brackets used?

Comment: Doesn't the operator `-le` means `less or equal`?

Comment: @JuiceBoxx see [How to use double or single bracket, parentheses, curly braces](//stackoverflow.com/q/2188199)

Comment: @mook765 good point, le= less than or equal to... I've updated the answer.